# AngularJS custom service injection

Tags: angularjs

i am learning angular and that is why some time i get stuck to understand the code. i got a code for custom service in angular. see the code first.

```
angular.module('yourModule').factory('alertService', function() {
    return {
        showError : function() {
            $.bigBox({
                title: title,
                content: content == null ? "An error occurred.<br /><br />If this error    persists, please contact support." : content,
                color: "#C46A69",
                //timeout: 6000,
                icon: "fa fa-warning shake animated",
                //number: "1",
                timeout: 3000
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Then you can inject it inside any controller and use it:

```
angular.module('yourModule').controller('yourController', function($scope, alertService) {
   someFunction().success(function (result) {
       // great!
   }).error(function (error) {
       // call standard error message function
       alertService.showError("Update Failed"); // use default error message
   });
});
```

### question 1

when injecting inbuilt service then we use $ sign like this way **$scope or $window etc** but when injecting custom one then just write the service name without $ sign why?

if we need to inject my own service with $ sign then any problem would occur ?
for $ sign do i need to create service with any specific code pattern ?

### question 2

```
showError : function() {

}
```

can we declare the above function name like this way

```
this.showError = function() {

  };

$scope.showError = function() {

    }
```

please rectify me if there is problem in my understanding.

Answer (score 5):

Question #1 
$ sign is used for angular built in services, so that you can differentiate core and built in services. You are recommended not to use $ for your own services

Question # 2: 
NO. You are returning an object and showError is a key of the object and a function as a value . An object key is always defined as

```
{
   showError: function (){
   }
}
```

The following patterns are normally used with controllers, rather than services.

```
this.showError = function() {
};

$scope.showError = function() {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Because angular services have have a $ in their name, and your service doesn't. It's a convention that angular adopted to make sure thet the framework service names don't clash with your own service names. If you name your own services with a $, you ruin it. So, don't name your services with a leading $.
2. No. A service can't be injected with a scope, since a service is global to the application, and not specific to a specific page. And using `this.showError` would bind the function to the factory, instead of binding it to the object (i.e. the service being defined) that is returned by the factory. You could use `this.showError` if you declared your service with the `service()` method rather than the `factory()` method. Read [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) for a description of the various ways to define a service.

Answer (score 1):

```js
//creating the module ,controller and registering with the module all done in one line
//Use the method chaining mechnism as show below:
var myApp = angular.module('myModule', []).controller("myController",function($scope,stringService){
 console.log("Hi");
 $scope.transformString = function(input){
  
  console.log("Hello");
  $scope.output = stringService.processString(input);
 }

 
});

//Above is Controller file//
//below is custom service.You can put into separate file and reuse it another Controller //
myApp.factory('stringService',function(){
  return {
   processString:function(input){
    if(!input){
    return input;
   }
   var output ="";
   for(var i = 0; i<input.length;i++){
    if(i > 0 && input[i] == input[i].toUpperCase()){
     output = output + " ";
    }
    output = output + input[i];
   }
   return output;

   }
  }
});
```

```css
table{
 border-collapse: collapse;
 font-family: Arial;
}
td{
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 5px;
}
th{
 border:1px solid black;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Angularjs- Custom Services in Angular</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="StringService.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body >
<p> What is a services in an Angular Application?<br>
 Why do we need services in an angular application?
 <br>
 What are the benefits of using services?
  
</p>
<div ng-app="myModule">
 <div ng-controller="myController">
 
 
 <table border="1">
  
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>Your String</td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="input" ></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Result</td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="output" ></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Process String" ng-click="transformString(input)" ></td>
   </tr>

  </tbody>
 </table>
 
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Above is custom services example for String Transforming eg: Input as"PramodKharade". output:"Pramod Kharade"

Comment: What exactly does this service?

Comment: If you will give input like PramodKharadeSoftwareDeveloper. This string will transform like Pramod Kharade Software Developer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the custom service simply given by AngularJs.
Using Service:

```
var module = angular.module('myapp', []);

module.service('userService', function(){
    this.users = ['John', 'James', 'Jake'];
});
```

you can also use factory method.

```
module.factory('userService', function(){

    var fac = {};

    fac.users = ['John', 'James', 'Jake']; 

    return fac;

});
```

For reference: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/